# Azure with ClearDB

Tags: php, mysql, sql, azure, cleardb

I have a php project that is connected to a ClearDB database. Running it locally has no issues and is able to interact with the database. But when I push the project to azure and try to run it from the website, it does not work with the database correctly. It seems to be able to connect to the database but inserts almost blank rows. For example, when I try to "register" it creates a row in the Users table with an ID but the name, username, etc. is all blank. I have no idea what is causing this. Are there any settings I have to change in Azure for it to be able to use that database or anything?

Thanks!

Comment: You have to be more specific here. What Azure Service are you using, what happens when you "register". Can you RDP on the machine and analyse your application. Please show some code for one specific problem you have.

Comment: This looks like an application failure, not a connectivity problem. Are you able to read from your DB (local and on Azure)? If true, check your configuration by logging your queries and use them on your cleardb instance.